# How do you alter the contents of an array with sed in BASH shell script?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, sed

I created an array of names of all files in the current directory ending with .cpp and want to create the same array with the .cpp replaced with .o

```
cppfield=$(ls *.cpp)
ofield=$(ls *.cpp | awk '{print}' ORS=' ' | sed s/.cpp/.o/g)
```

but it is not working only the first argument has the .cpp switched with .o

Comment: surprisingly I cannot replicate it.

Comment: `cppfield=$(ls *.cpp)` does not create an array it creates a string. If you want an array use `cppfield(*.cpp)`. Which actually creates an array and lets you use filenames with spaces/etc. safely.

Comment: @EtanReisner i would change the IFS to `IFS=$'\n'` when using `cppfield=($(ls -1 *.cpp))`. what am i missing in your snippet > `cppfield(*.cpp)` to avoid handling files with spaces seperately?

Comment: Messing with `IFS` is only part of the issue. I'm not sure I understand the second question.

Comment: "lets you use filenames with spaces/etc. safely" worries me. i thought there are problems with the default IFS and whitespaces in a filename when creating array. does your snippet actually handle that? if so, why? hope my question is more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pattern substitution when you expand the array:

```
bash> a=(a.cpp b.cpp);
bash> a=("${a[@]/%.cpp/.o}");
bash> echo "${a[@]}";
a.o b.o
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying to do.

```
$ ls
a1.cpp  a2.cpp  a3.cpp  a4.cpp  a5.cpp  a6.cpp
$ cppfield=(*.cpp)
$ declare -p cppfield
declare -a cppfield='([0]="a1.cpp" [1]="a2.cpp" [2]="a3.cpp" [3]="a4.cpp" [4]="a5.cpp" [5]="a6.cpp")'
$ ofield=("${cppfield[@]/%.cpp/.o}")
$ declare -p ofield
declare -a ofield='([0]="a1.o" [1]="a2.o" [2]="a3.o" [3]="a4.o" [4]="a5.o" [5]="a6.o")'
```

Use globbing to fill in the array to handle filenames safely. [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Use [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to replace `.cpp` with `.o` on every array element.

Expand an array in quotes and store the result in a new array.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ls` to get directory contents for further processing.  It will be hard to handle the file names which have spaces and newlines in them correctly.

Better you use `find` like this:

```
x() { sed 's/\.cpp$/.o/' <<< "$1"; }
export -f x
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c 'x "{}"' \;
```

Now the answer is not about arrays anymore, but that's because I want to point out that storing the output of `ls` in an array is already the beginning of the problem.  Maybe avoid arrays for this task altogether.